# 'Framed' tomcat6 losing sessions

Tags: java, jsp, session, tomcat6, genesys

IWS is a desktop application with its own webBrowser component to call Scripting web-app when needed. Scripting is located in a Tomcat6.

Scripting is basically an JSP application. (Really it is an engine who builds an JSP application from the human actions over its graphical interface, like define flows, buttons, content, etc, but I am talking about the "Script" it generates as an JSP)

I need to hack Scripting so it can share space (via frames) in that webBrowser component of IWS application.

The IWS call 2 times to start.jsp:

- the first time, in a hidden way (probably a direct http query from IWS code), without any special parameters. The original start.jsp do 2 302 (so the call visits 3 pages total) it ends using the jsesionId both in cookie and as a parameter (but not at the last 302)
- second time, with the jSessionId and a bunch of important parameters. It only uses the jSessionId as the parameter. As far as I have seen in fiddler, no cookie is used when it works correctly as jsessionId is inside its own

So I guess that the first time ìt is just to get a new jSessionId.

The solution I am trying now is to replace Scripting starting page with a new frames page which, in one of the two frames it holds, it loads the web aplication, and another application in the second frame. Depending on data from the first frame it will update the second frame.

So something like to:

- we had start.jsp... (really it is called something different)
- and we end with:

  - start.app.jsp (which is original start.jsp, just renamed)
  - start.jsp (is the new  including html which  wraps the previous start.jsp)

The new start.jsp uses its own url, changing start.jsp into start.app.jsp, to invoke the true Scripting application inside an iframe.

But I have been suffering from like session problems. I am not an expert in tomcat. I learned that it controls the session with cookies or with parameters. I think it is configured to work with the URL sessionId but I am not really sure. I have set META-INF/settings.xml to disable cookie use in sessions, but it still show the cookie in the cookies list.

My problem is that in that second time start.jsp is called, it appear than somethink like an "old cookie" is being used, ignoring the jsessionId from the URL. Some weird errors appear at WWG00000E: WWGAIL - Error: ID was not provided for function getInteractionKVPair  Detail:

It is like it is returning to an old cookie with another jsessionid. That 'old' jsessionid is the same each time the error shows up.

*Sniffing with fiddler, I see that the second start.jsp starts with the right jsessionId in the URL, but its cookies are like from another session, and it stops to add the jsession id with each redirection since this happens. It is like it is executing in a completely different universe. Is this normal?????*

Currently I am trying without avail to force the cookie jSessionId and also the links so they include the jSessionId.

Please, do you have any idea?

Thanks!

Edited2: if I place it without frames (restoring default start.jsp). At IWS works only the first time (interaction), while in any subsequent one the problem start to appear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, solved at last...

At least with this version of Tomcat:

- A call to a jsp without jSessionId creates a new jSessionId in your app cookie.
- Any further on in time html request will use the cookie jSessionId instead of the one present on the URL, so you lose any type of multisession support.

It is something special than in a webBrowser component, doing a two steps connections, the first request never have an associated cookie, so it works OK, giving you a cookie with a new jSessionId, and then you can do a new, cookieless, second request which uses the jSessionId of the URL and have not cookie or have "a default" cookie without jSessionId. When this webBrowser requests a jsp page without jSessionId in its URL, as said, the problem starts, so if the first request includes a non jSessionIded call, Tomcat gives you a jSessionId which is set on your "default app cookie", so the second request ignores any URL jSessionId to use the one on that cookie.

In a web browser, I have observed that in at least firefox, cleaning the cookies is not enough to eliminate this "default cookie". But maybe it could be the classic "It takes too long so you think it is clean but really it is not". Not sure.

I know this sounds confusing. I have not the time to do further testing about this.

As far as I have understood, it is like, when it works OK, it is working like with an "session cookie" (without jSessionId), while when it does not work it takes the "default cookie" (with jSessionId) and starts ignoring URL jSessionId.

I have sent an email to the dev mailinglist of Tomcat. (One said that the correct place was the user mailinglist... but here you are ;-) )